# Using MAX with unsigned long and unsigned long subtraction

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion

The `NSArray`'s `count` is a `NSUInteger`. When the array is *empty*, the following line sets `-1` to `p` (at first glance, someone could guess `p` will become `0`).

```
NSInteger p = MAX(0, array.count - 1)
```

I assume, the reason is that `array.count - 1` is interpreted by the `MAX` macro as 18446744073709551615 instead of -1, so it returns this value as larger of two but, because `p` is a `long`, then it converts the large number to -1. Am I wrong here?

So, is it safe to use MAX to compare integers?

For example, it is possible to write a loop, which in a particular case when `a.count == 0`, intuitively looks like exiting immediately but in fact is proceeds with zillions of iterations, freezing or crashing the device. Is this because the constrain is interpreted as `w < 18446744073709551615` ?.

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
for(NSInteger w = 0; w < MAX(0, a.count-1); w++)
{
    NSLog(@"w = %li",w);
}
```

I guess, that a safe method would be writing:

```
NSInteger q = array.count - 1;
NSInteger p = MAX(0, q);
```

... which would set zero to `p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `MAX` is save. Not safe is using `.count - 1`.

Your's cycle should be:

```
for(NSInteger w = 0; 1 + w < a.count; ++w)
{
    NSLog(@"w = %li",w);
}
```